# Javascript JSON.parse SUB JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Ok I know this sounds stupid, because the code below should be working

```
document.getElementById('petimg').src = petJSON[0].picture[0].large;
```

however it keeps crashing the site

here is the full code

```
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://service.ipetfindr.com/iOS/?uri=fetchpet/13373A" + n[1],false);
xmlhttp.send();

var petJSON = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

alert(petJSON[0].picture.large);

document.getElementById('petimg').src = petJSON[0].picture.[0].large;
document.getElementById("petname").innerHTML = petJSON[0].petname;
document.getElementById("breed").innerHTML = petJSON[0].breed;
document.getElementById("petid").innerHTML = petJSON[0].ipetfindrtagid;
```

The part of the JSON I am having an issue with is the following

```
"picture":[{"large":"http:\/\/www.ipetfindr.com\/petuploads\/7b2b07363b271703782d0b7d5362f8f4.JPG","small":"http:\/\/www.ipetfindr.com\/petuploads\/7b2b07363b271703782d0b7d5362f8f4-x-h80.JPG"}]
```

**EDIT FIX**
the way to fix this error was simple

```
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://service.ipetfindr.com/iOS/?uri=fetchpet/13373A" + n[1],false);
xmlhttp.send();

var petJSON = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
var petpicture = petJSON[0].picture[0];
alert(petpicture.large); //THIS allows me or anyone to call the large image in the sub array

document.getElementById('petimg').src = petJSON[0].picture.[0].large;
document.getElementById("petname").innerHTML = petJSON[0].petname;
document.getElementById("breed").innerHTML = petJSON[0].breed;
document.getElementById("petid").innerHTML = petJSON[0].ipetfindrtagid;
```

Comment: Show us the exception you are getting (from the error console)

Comment: I am not seeing any error in the console, because its a phonegap app which crashes

Comment: Could it be your XHR is hanging. You are using blocking mode on it, so if its taking a while to recieve it could crash the site/app

Comment: Without any attempt to debugging, we hardly will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`petJSON[0].picture.[0].large` is a syntax error. Remove the dot from before the `[`, you can only use either dot or bracket notation to [access properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators).